# setStatusBarHidden is deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I am upgrading my code from iOS 8 to iOS 9. I have a code snippet in my program
`[[UIApplication applicationName] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`.

I am getting the warning "setStatusBarHidden is deprecated in iOS 9.0, Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden". If I just replace 'setStatusBarHidden' with 'prefersStatusBarHidden', I get 'instance method not found'.
Can someone please suggest me how to solve this problem?

Comment: `prefersStatusBarHidden` is a method of UIViewController objects, not UIApplication. So you should set it on each UIViewController.

Comment: @user1963877 Thank you. As I am new to iOS programming, can you please let me know how to set it on each UIViewController. 'applicationName' is of type UIApplication.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add below code to your view controller..

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {

   return NO;
}
```

**Note :**

- If you change the return value for this method, call the
  `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method.
- For childViewController, To specify that a child view controller
  should control preferred status bar hidden/unhidden state, implement
  the `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` method.

Comment: How is this the solution? 

preferStatusBarHidden existed before iOS 9. It can only be applied to the view controller so if you want to more dynamically hide or show the status bar how do you handle that in iOS 9?

How would you for example show or hide the status bar based on the user touching a button on the screen?

Comment: @PolarBear You can apply logic like this,  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    shouldHideStatusBar = (shouldHideStatusBar)? NO: YES;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

Comment: You can add this code to your button event as well.

Comment: @NileshPatel Thanks for the help here. I ended up figuring out how to correctly change it just on my root controller with your idea. Thanks again.

One tip, make sure to add to your info.plist 
"View controller-based status bar appearance" set to YES otherwise things just don't seem to work.

Comment: How can the act of it hiding be animated?

Answer (score 6):

[prefersStatusBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden) is available from iOS 7+.

Use this in Your `UIViewController` class

```
   var isHidden = true{
        didSet{
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return isHidden
    }
```

[image]

> If you change the return value for this method, call the
>   setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() method. To specify that a child
>   view controller should control preferred status bar hidden/unhidden
>   state, implement the childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden method.

Answer (score 5):

you have to add method in yourViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {

   return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.1 Xcode 8.2.1**

1. Change in info.plist the row View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO
2. In your target settings tick "Hide Status bar"

Both steps are required

Answer (score 2):

Here is my swift code for setting status bar hidden and style.

```
extension UIViewController {

public var privateStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}

public var privateStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return statusBarStyle
}

public func setStatusBarHidden(hidden: Bool, animated: Bool = false) {
    statusBarHidden = hidden
    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { 
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        })
    } else {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}

public func setStatusBar(style: UIStatusBarStyle) {
    statusBarStyle = style
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

    public static func swizzleStatusBarHiddenPropertyForViewController() {
    var original = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(getter: UIViewController.prefersStatusBarHidden))
    var changeling = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(getter: UIViewController.privateStatusBarHidden))
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, changeling)
    original = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(getter: UIViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle))
    changeling = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(getter: UIViewController.privateStatusBarStyle))
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, changeling)

    original = class_getClassMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.swizzleStatusBarHiddenPropertyForViewController))
    changeling = class_getClassMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.emptyFunction))
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, changeling)
}

@objc private static func emptyFunction() {}
}
```

#### Usage

- in lauching function

> UIViewController.swizzleStatusBarHiddenPropertyForViewController()

- for hide/show statusBar, in UIViewController

. self.setStatusBar(hidden: true/false)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 with Xcode 8.3.3**

1) Add a row in you Info.plist.
[image]

2) In your ViewController ViewDidLoad() override add:

```
 UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

Comment: 'isStatusBarHidden' is also deprecated

Comment: That’s right. What I did next was to add a property in info.plist called ‘View Controller based statusbar..’ with Boolean ‘NO’ and in project General setting I changed ‘status bar type’ to ‘light’.