# setStatusBarHidden deprecated, but only thing that works

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode6, ios9

I've tried all the solutions I can find including those in: [setStatusBarHidden is deprecated in iOS 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114340/setstatusbarhidden-is-deprecated-in-ios-9-0) but none of them work with my application.

It is a simple, single view application. There is a Navigation bar with a single button on it which the status bar should show on top of.

In my .plist:

> Status bar is initially hidden: NO
>
> Status bar style: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
>
> View Controller based status bar appearance: NO

Changing any of these doesn't seem to make any difference at all. I have the status bar style "Hide during application launch" option checked as I don't want it to appear on the splash screen.

I have:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden 
{
    return NO;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    NSLog(@"style");
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

and `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` which are definitely all called when the view loads in my ViewController.

The view is established in a .storyboard, but many of the fields are manipulated in the ViewController.m as well. The value assigned to the status bar in the simulated metrics doesn't seem to have any effect either.

I need my status bar to be hidden during the launch screen and visible on the viewController. Please help me find a solution that doesn't use the deprecated setStatusbarHidden!

**EDIT:**

I still haven't solved this, and I surely can't be the only one with this problem! It happens in both apps that I have written.

Comment: `ViewController based status bar appearance` should set to `YES` to use `preferedStatusBarStyle` which should return `UIStatusBarStyleNone`.

Comment: `UIStatusBarStyleNone` is not a declared identifier of `preferredStatusBarStyle`

Comment: sorry. I was confused. `return YES` with `prefersSatusBarHidden`.

Comment: That hides the status bar on the view controller. I want it showing on the view controller and hidden for the launch screen.

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: Have the exact same problem.  No idea why this seemingly simple task is so frustrating!

Answer (score 7):

I've just been trying to solve the same problem, I don't know why the setStatusBarHidden and setStatusBarStyle have been deprecated as the new methods are not at all intuitive.

To hide the status bar on launch I have these settings in  my plist:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance: YES
Status bar is initially hidden: YES
```

Then to show the status bar after launch I have in my view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {    
    return NO;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

This still didn't work until I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19365160/488611. So in viewDidLoad I also set the navigation bar style:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Which makes absolutely no sense, but works.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
application.statusBarHidden=YES;
```

in AppDelegate.m

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

Comment: deprecated as well

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, you should change the value of `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`.

Set the value file .plist of project a is

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO`

and check in file AppDelegate and set the code

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Hope my solution can be solved your problem.

Comment: I already have UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO set in the .plist as stated in the question, and setStatusBarStyle is a deprecated method. This does not help me, but thank you for trying.

Comment: change `setStatusBarStyle`. Try it code.
`-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
} `

Answer (score 0):

OK, I totally misunderstood your question. Here's the correct answer.

Add the below value to you 'info.plist'.

```
Status bar is initially hidden : YES
View Controller based status bar appearance : YES
```

On `UIViewController`s which you want to show status bar

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Still not working. The ONLY thing which seems to make any difference (apart from the deprecated setStatusBarHidden) is whether or not I set "Hide during application launch" in the General Target settings. I've tried playing with the "Requires full-screen" setting as well to see if this was having an effect. Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this, but I played with these settings for some time and came to the following conclusions.

General/Deployment Info:
Status Bar Style: Default (black), Light
Hide status bar (checkbox)
Both change the status bar on the launch screen only.
Note that if you take a screen shot to create this image and the screen shot included a status bar, it will appear that the device is setting the status bar even if you have checked the Hide status bar checkbox! I was tricked by this for a while before I finally thought to look at the launch image itself, and there was a status bar in the photo, so setting Hide never seemed to work even though it really was working. I removed the status bar from the images themselves using Photoshop, and the launch status bars functioned as expected after that.

Info/Custom iOS Target Properties (these change the values in the PLIST, so you could change them in either place):
Status Bar Is Initially Hidden: Yes/No
Status Bar Style: Gray (default), Transparent Black, Opaque Black
View Controller based status bar appearance : Yes/No
If you set Status Bar Is Initially Hidden to No, then you will have the status bar on your View Controller like you wanted. If you want to hide the status bar on your View Controller, you have to set Status Bar Is Initially Hidden to Yes AND set View Controller based status bar appearance to No.

Attributes Inspector for the View Controller/Simulated Metrics
Status Bar: None, Inferred, Default, Light, Black (deprecated)
This seems to have no effect on anything except the appearance of the view controllers in the StoryBoard but NOT in the simulator.

Summary: To answer your question, under General Deployment Info, check the checkbox that says Hide Status Bar. This will hide the status bar on the launch screen. Make certain that your image for the launch screen does NOT have a picture of a status bar in it. None of the settings in the StoryBoard or in the Target seems to turn off the view controller's status bar, so it seems that it will stay on like you wanted. However, I did not test any of the programmatic settings; I think that you should not do any of those, and it will work the way you want.

Comment: My launch screen picture definitely doesn't have a status bar on it, it's a completely different image from the what appears on the ViewController.