# UINavigationController's navigation bar overlaps with Status bar when user plays a video in webview

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, statusbar, xcode9.2

I'm using UINavigationController, works fine, problem occurs when I play a video inside a Webview & change device orientation, then navigation bar of controller overlaps with status bar, screenshot attached. I've seen these solutions [ios 11 custom navbar goes under status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326554/ios-11-custom-navbar-goes-under-status-bar/46327172#46327172)
, [ios 11 navigation bar overlap status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362277/ios-11-navigation-bar-overlap-status-bar/46920367#46920367)
, but those solutions apply while not using navigation controller since I can't change properties of navigationController's navigation bar, any suggestions ? [image]

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to solve this issue, here is the solution that worked for me

```
open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateStatusBar), name: Notification.Name.UIWindowDidBecomeKey, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateStatusBar), name: Notification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}
```

and

```
@objc func updateStatusBar() {
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```