# Can't Hide Status Bar—Swift 3,

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I usually hide the status bar with

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

but Xcode is giving me an error, saying "Method does not override anything from its superclass".

If I delete the `override`, Xcode gives a different error: "Method 'prefersStatusBarHidden()' with Objective-C selector 'prefersStatusBarHidden' conflicts with getter for 'prefersStatusBarHidden' from superclass 'UIViewController' with the same Objective-C selector"

---

I also have "Hide Status Bar" checked in my Target's general settings:

[image]

but the status bar still shows up.

---

I found this method in another Stack Overflow answer

```
UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .none)
```

but that doesn't hide the status bar either.

---

In Xcode 8 Beta 1, I used the first and second methods, which worked to hide the status bar (the first method did not return an error). What can I do now to hide the status bar, with Xcode 8 Beta 4?

Note: The status bar shows up on Simulator devices and physical devices, all running iOS 10.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31129671/5109911

Comment: @SaintThread Thank you but see the first part of my question about why using `func prefersStatusBarHidden` just isn't working. Any other ideas?

Comment: @matt I don't think this is a duplicate because that answer is explicitly about interface orientation, which is different than what I'm talking about here. It also doesn't cover the `get { return true }` covered here, and doesn't cover the other types of methods that failed for me. It's just not complete enough to be an answer for my question.

Comment: @JohnRamos Did you even _read_ my answer? It happens that the _question_ was about interface orientation, but my _answer_ covers your situation exactly, explaining what has changed in Swift 3 Xcode 8 seed 4 (i.e. certain view controller methods are now properties that you override as properties). My answer is _extremely_ complete and explicitly includes `prefersStatusBarHidden`.

Comment: @matt I did indeed read your answer and saw that it included a prefersStatusBarHidden reference. I just don't think it covers with such simplicity and specificity the particular topic at hand as does Anbu's answer (which I edited to include a more info reference to your detailed answer). I agree that your answer could work with some edits as an answer to this question, I just don't think it quite fits as is. I just don't think this unique question deserves a [duplicate] tag given how different your answer and its accompanying question is to my question and its accepted answer here.

Comment: [set status bar with code dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43752721/6521116)

Comment: @KrisRoofe Indeed, your question is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @owlswipe, no in my quesiton I need to hide or show with user event. Not config it to the stable status.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Ok, my bad. Cool stuff.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

We need to override the property itself on Swift 3 (this is new in Xcode 8 Beta 4):

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {  
    return true  
}
```

---

**updated Swift 5+**

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { true }
```

for another example also you can get [here](http://ios.qahowto.com/setStatusBarHidden_withAnimation-deprecated-in-iOS-9-ios-swift-ios9-statusbar-1f49e91) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app)

For more on what this change is and why it's necessary, see [Matt's great answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732957/5700898).

Comment: @JohnRamos - happy to hear..

Comment: how do you do this in Objective-C ?

Comment: @omarojo Obj C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146012/hide-status-bar-in-ios-8-app

Comment: just use override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
  return true
 }

Comment: if you need to make a change hide the status bar ...say on completion of something - like an animation. In the completion block just do    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true => This will work with Swift 3

Comment: I think it's a method not a var... `public func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool`

Comment: @HuguesBR Not in Swift 3

Comment: @LeoDabus true thx :)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I have done as suggested by you but when I return from background to foregroud, status bar appears again :(

Comment: It works for a single page only. For hiding status for whole app, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app

Comment: It works for me !!!

Comment: Shortcut for Swift 5+: `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { true }`

Comment: @Rick - thanks you, answer updated.