# Method does not override in Superclass Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am convert my code in swift 3 They give me error method does not override in superclass.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {

    var statusBarHidden: Bool

    switch statusBarStyle {
    case .hidden:
        statusBarHidden = true
    default:
        statusBarHidden = false
    }

    if visible || contentViewContainer.frame.origin.y <= 0, let cntViewController = contentViewController {
        statusBarHidden = cntViewController.prefersStatusBarHidden
    }

    return statusBarHidden
}
```

Comment: In Swift 3 it is property not method use like `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }`

Comment: prefersStatusBarHidden changed from a function to a property in Swift 3 check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38876435/1390857

Comment: Thanks .. It working