# Xcode 8.2: Swift3- how to hide status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

***all trying to hide status bar with Xcode 8.2 with swift 3. but I can't hide it.***

[image]

[image]

and also for,

[image]

Comment: @jhon `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true` not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide the status bar in a Swift iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app)

Comment: @NiravD not working!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can Approach this in two ways

> **Option 1**.Try this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` Method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true

    return true
}
```

> **Option 2**. override`prefersStatusBarHidden` function  in your `UIViewController`

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true
}
```

**Note:** you call `override func prefersStatusBarHidden` it should be `override var prefersStatusBarHidden`

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3 use this,

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {  
    return true  
}
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38876435/6742121)

Comment: plz see last screenshot of question.

Answer (score 1):

override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your view controller

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return true
    }
```

true if the status bar should be hidden or false if it should be shown.

Refer [apple doc link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden)