# set status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

How  to hide, show or change the status bar dynamically on events such as click or value change?

I've googled for a well, but all I get is changed from the beginning as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7). Here I need to do it dynamically.

Comment: For manually config the status bar, refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38876249/6521116).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for this you can do following based on events:

```
//For hiding/unhiding:
    func hideStatusBar(shouldHide:Bool){
     UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = shouldHide
    }

    //For Light Style:
    func lightStatusBar(){
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }

    //For Standard Style:
    func standardStatusBar(){
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default

    }
```

or you can tweak `prefersStatusBarHidden`: as well.

Answer (score 1):

UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden=true

Comment: Yes it is in Swift 2

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { get }`

Override that function in your view controller. Dynamically update the visibility of your statusbar with func `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden