# Hide the iOS status bar on Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

Is there any way to hide the status bar in an iOS application?

I tried with [this soluton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/hide-android-status-bar-on-flutter-app) to do it in Android, but it doesn't work on iOS.

In addition, I also tried hiding it by using the native iOS way to do it, but the `FlutterViewController` is being regenerated in every build, so I can't apply the solution described [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543470/hide-status-bar-swift-4).

Comment: Did you try particularly this one - SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]); ? It works for me at least

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to call `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);`.

Comment: `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` this alone is sufficient, you don't need to change anything in `info.plist` file.

Comment: @Volleyball, yeah it's true. Some funny business is happening in this man's app)

Comment: You're totally right. I made too much changes in the same time and ended with a working project but didn't notice that one commit wasn't needed. Thanks guys!