# Xcode Hide white status bar ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, statusbar

I want white status bar in my app. For this I set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` and `Status bar style` to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`. But now I need to hide status bar in some view controllers. To hide it I have to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` and add `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {return YES;}`. But status bar is black now. It's black when `View controller-based status bar appearance` is `YES` and white if `NO`. So the question is, how to set white status bar and hide it?

UPD:
code in VC that I want to have white status bar (`prefferdSTatusBarStyle` not called)

[image]

code in VC with hidden status bar

[image]

.plist settings

[image]

Result is black status bar, that hides in some VC

UPD2:

I know it's bad to use deprecated methods but with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` everything works as I want. If anyone have better solution please let me know.

Comment: you have to display "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent" in every viewcontroller of your project?

Comment: Yes. All view controllers should be with white status bar

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a status bar in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661031/how-to-hide-a-status-bar-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set using xcode status bar style is "light"

[image]

Comment: you have do any changes in info.plist file for status bar ?

Comment: only `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES` and `Status bar style` set to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`. but status bar is black now

Comment: you have to set View controller-based status bar appearance set to "NO"

Comment: if I set in to `NO` I will not be able to hide status bar with `prefersStatusBarHidden`

Comment: you have try this code ? - (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133245/discussion-between-birendra-and-ossir).

Answer (score 5):

This is the swift version:

To hide the status bar or change it's appearance, you need to override the following properties in your view controller itself

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
}
```

the above hides the status bar and below if you want to set it to white:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your plist file add `View controller-based status bar appearance` Bool property and set it to YES.

Now in your view controller add the methods like below:

```
// TO MAKE STATUS BAR WHITE
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
}

// TO MAKE STATUS BAR BLACK
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
}

// RETURN TRUE TO HIDE AND FALSE TO SHOW STATUS BAR
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

For **Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

For removing redundant code you can make a `BaseViewController` as subclass of `UIViewController` and add the methods in that class. And override the method in the class which requires change.

Comment: don't know what wrong but when I do this I have black status bar and `preferredStatusBarStyle` not called.  `prefersStatusBarHidden` works

Comment: @Ossir Did you set the bool to YES in plist?

Comment: yes. `prefersStatusBarHidden` works and  `preferredStatusBarStyle` no

Comment: @Ossir Make sure that method is not getting override from anywhere else?

Comment: yes. I searched it in my project and have only one result

Comment: @Ossir Are you using navigation controller?

Comment: I have UITabBarController as root VC

Comment: it's exactly like in your post. I will update my question

Comment: @Ossir http://stackoverflow.com/a/31129671/4715546 check the link i know i am late for reply but have a look once.

Answer (score 0):

if your viewcontroller is embedded in UInavigationController then try writing this code in your

```
-(BOOL)prefreStatusBarHidden
{
       return [self.navigationController prefersStatusBarHidden];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by setting the navigation background image in your base viewcontroller.

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_navigationbar"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:bgImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```