# StatusBar ins't calling preferredStatusBarStyle when setting View controller-based status bar appearance = YES

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

The title says it all. Or have something VERY wrong whit me to understand the sdk, or something is VERY wrong with apple's sdk.

When setting ***(info.plist)*** View controller-based status.. = YES, I can hide my statusbar animated and whatever, by calling setNeedsStatusBarEtc... But then, I cant change my preferredStatusBarStyle. And When I set it to NO, I can change the style, but not everything else.. What do I do? What's is wrong? Please, some help!

When ***controller-based status.. = YES***

So in my ViewController I create a statusBarHidden: Bool and override class var: prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool, preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: Bool and preferredStatusBarStyle to change my statusBar.

```
var statusBarHidden = false {
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { () -> Void in
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

But then, this code will call prefersStatusBarHidden and preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation only, but not preferredStatusBarStyle. Whit ***controller-based status.. = NO***, it is called, but the others isn't. I just want a lightContent StatusBar hiding in some VCs..

**A deprecated solution:**

```
 UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

But can't animate (at least I couldn't)

Thanks to  @WillBoland

Comment: post your code, please.

Comment: @BJHStudios updated!

Comment: @Gehlen , more code ,please. It is difficult to understand you. 'l prefersStatusBarHidden and preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation' - where do you use this? 'Whit NO, it is called.' - what does it mean? Make your post more clear, please.

Comment: @Vyacheslav updated!

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670828/xcode-hide-white-status-bar-ios-10/41671143#41671143

Comment: Look at this discussion: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133245/discussion-between-birendra-and-ossir

Comment: @WillBoland thanks for that. Looks like this deprecated method is working: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO] 
But I'll wait for non deprecated solution.. (I didn't tried this yet); If it works with swift I'll update with solution suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Even though it is in Objective-C, still works. Hopefully there will be a non-depracated solution.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Sulthan need more context? What is your doubt? Essentially, what I want is hide/show status bar animated and change its style. But looks like you can't do both things.. Maybe its a semantic error with the sdk? Until now, I couldn't find any solution that isn't deprecated (and even with deprecated solution - I can't animate the hide action)... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As Per [this link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133245/discussion-between-birendra-and-ossir/), using the following worked.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]
```

It is deprecated though.

Comment: It works, but besides being deprecated, I'm also unable to animate.. =(

Comment: Ah, so sorry. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Me too! Thank you!