# how to hide status bar in ios 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, statusbar, appdelegate

i have already checked the answer which is given in stack overflow.
  like this method:     `prefersStatusBarHidden`

```
      -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
       return [self.navigationController prefersStatusBarHidden];
       }
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670828/xcode-hide-white-status-bar-ios-10)

Answer (score 0):

Create and import a category of navigation controller like below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationController (StatusBarStyle)

- (void)setDefaultStatusBar;
- (void)setLightStatusBar;

@end

#import "UINavigationController+StatusBarStyle.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (StatusBarStyle)
BOOL isLight;

- (void)setDefaultStatusBar {
    isLight=NO;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (void)setLightStatusBar {
    isLight=YES;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    if (isLight) {
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }
    else{
        return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
    }
}

@end
```

And call `[self.navigationController setDefaultStatusBar]` or `[self.navigationController setLightStatusBar]` from your viewDidLoad or somewhere from your view controller which has a parent `UINavigationController`